# Cannot access member variable in method call

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm building a parser for PE files and I've encountered a somewhat weird error. Here is the minimal example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>


class BinaryDataSegment {
protected:
    std::vector<uint8_t>* binary_data;   
    int data_size;

public:   
    BinaryDataSegment(){
        data_size = 0;
    }

    BinaryDataSegment(std::istream& field_data, int reserve_size) {
        binary_data = new std::vector<uint8_t>();
        binary_data->reserve(reserve_size);
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(field_data), std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(), std::back_inserter(*binary_data));
        data_size = binary_data->size();
    }

    template<typename D>
    D Read(int position){
        if (position + sizeof(D) > data_size){
            throw std::overflow_error("attempting to read outsite binary data");
        }
        D temp;
        std::cout << binary_data->data()+position << std::endl; // Segmentation fault here: binary_data is not accessible
        memcpy(&temp, binary_data->data()+position, sizeof(D));
        return temp;
    }

    ~BinaryDataSegment(){
        delete binary_data;
    }
};

class PEFile {
protected:
    BinaryDataSegment data;

public:
    PEFile(std::istream& file_stream, int reserve=0){
        data = BinaryDataSegment(file_stream, reserve);
    }
    int dos_header;

    void parse(){
        dos_header = data.Read<int>(0);
    }
};

int main(){
    std::ifstream in_file = std::ifstream("anyFile.txt", std::ios::binary);
    PEFile foo = PEFile(in_file, 0);
    foo.parse(); // Segmentation fault

    BinaryDataSegment bar = BinaryDataSegment(in_file, 0);
    bar.Read<int>(0); // This works correctly
    
}
```

When I call the `Read<int>` function from `main`, it works correctly, but when I do it from the `PEFile` class, the same function call fails with a Segmentation fault. GDB says that the memory of `binary_data` is not accessible, even though it looks like it should be. My question is: why does this unexpected behavior happen?

I compiled without warnings using:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 example.cpp
```

When running the example, make sure to replace "anyFile.txt" with a real local file. Thank you.

Comment: Your class [violates the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The easiest  fix is to stop using `new` to create a vector, and just create it directly as a class member.

Comment: To expand a bit - look at `data = BinaryDataSegment(file_stream, reserve);`. A temporary `BinaryDataSegment` is constructed, allocating an instance of `vector` on the heap and storing a pointer to it in `binary_data` member. This temporary is then assigned to `data`; since you didn't provide `operator=`, an implicitly-defined one simply copies over data members. So `data.binary_data` now points to the same vector on the heap as the temporary's `binary_data`. Finally, the temporary is destroyed, and its destructor deallocates the vector. `data` ends up holding a dangling pointer.

Comment: Besides making the class hold a vector directly rather than allocate one on the heap, you can also construct `data` directly in `PEFile` constructor, as in `PEFile(std::istream& file_stream, int reserve=0) : data(file_stream, reserve) {}` You may wish to review the section about [constructor initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) in your favorite C++ textbook.